# Installing oracle database express edition error /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin/nls_lang.sh: No such file or directory

Tags: oracle

I am trying to install the oracle database express from [here](https://tec600.wordpress.com/2017/06/29/oracle-installation-on-ubuntu-16-04/), but after adding the following lines to the ~/.bashrc:

```
export PYTHONPATH EDITOR
export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe
export ORACLE_SID=XE
export NLS_LANG=`$ORACLE_HOME/bin/nls_lang.sh`
export ORACLE_BASE=/u01/app/oracle
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

and then running  `~/.profile` I get this error:
bash: /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin/nls_lang.sh: No such file or directory

Comment: Remove or comment out that line. I don't think `nls_lang.sh` exists in Oracle binaries

Comment: What is the purpose of `$ORACLE_HOME/bin/nls_lang.sh`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is because you are installing a newer version of the Oracle Express DB, I would check the version you downloaded, as the tutorial is a bit outdated and then just update everything along the way to reflect the changes.

First, make sure the version you have downloaded is different than the one in the tutorial.

You could also try to see if ORACLE_HOME exists by doing the following:

```
cd /u01/app/oracle/product/
```

Then check the version folder to see if it is a different version.

The version available for download right now on Oracle's website is 18.4.0. If the folder is named 18.4.0, then the config should be the following:

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/18.4.0/xe
export ORACLE_SID=XE
export NLS_LANG=`$ORACLE_HOME/bin/nls_lang.sh`
export ORACLE_BASE=/u01/app/oracle
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

If that does not work, reinstall the whole thing again changing the version number to match the version you downloaded.

Comment: I installed the 18.04 version, but I can't find the /u01/ folder. I was only able to find the oracle folder in /opt/ should I use that path instead

Answer (score 0):

Remove the back-ticks from your definition of NLS_LANG:

```
ed@ed-Gazelle-00:~$ export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe
ed@ed-Gazelle-00:~$ export NLS_LANG=`$ORACLE_HOME/bin/nls_lang.sh`
bash: /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin/nls_lang.sh: No such file or directory
ed@ed-Gazelle-00:~$ export NLS_LANG=$ORACLE_HOME/bin/nls_lang.sh
ed@ed-Gazelle-00:~$
```

Why did you have them there in the first place?

Comment: It worked after I changed the path or ORACLE_HOME to /opt/oracle/product and commented  export NLS_LANG=$ORACLE_HOME/bin/nls_lang.sh in the ~/.bashrc file. I guess there really wasn't any purpose to it in this version after all

Comment: It wasn't the presence of the NLS_LANG variable, per se.  It was because you were setting it incorrectly.  Your reported error was _not_ at the point of installing oracle, it was at the point of trying to set an environment variable.  Nothing about oracle was involved at that point.  Do you understand what the back-tics do in a shell statement?